# Clipping between features within a single vector?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, pyqgis, clip

Is it possible (via the Qgis API and friends), to clip polygonal features **within** a single vector layer?

The hope is to accomplish this without having to duplicate the feature into a new layer.  Brief experimentation with the *processing.runalg("qgis:clip"...)*  command only showed me capabilities to accomplish such between multiple layers rather than multiple features WITHIN one layer.

Thanks!